# Chat TableView Cell: A UIView, whose size should depend on the larger containing label

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I want to make a chat table cell, with content label and a time label.

Requirements are:

1. The blue UIView's size (width) should depend on the wider label within it.
2. The UIView should leave at least 61 dpi to the right of the cell.
3. The label should be able to wrap the text inlined in it.

This is the structure:

[image: Structure]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Give the label constraints that go to the edges of its superview according to what you want

Set constraints on the view so that its size is not restricted to a specific height, e.g. use a combination of constraints with lower priorities and inequality constraints (i.e. greater or less than or equal to). Not entirely sure what your goal is so I can't really be more specific.

Set the number of lines of the label to 0

Comment: Great Thanks! I figured out another way by setting the increasing hugging and lower resistance with identical constraints for these 2 labels.